# How to correctly call / render react code in html?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to display elements written in a js file using react, here's the class:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";


const e = React.createElement;

class StartPage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <h2>...0</h2>
                <h3>...1</h3>
                <p>...3</p>
                <p>...2</p>
                <div id="current_date_time"></div>
                <h:link outcome="main">Go to main page</h:link>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
const domContainer = document.querySelector('#test');
ReactDOM.render(StartPage, domContainer);
```

here's the html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script type="text/js" src="js/start.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="test"/>
</body>
</html>
```

But there is nothing on startup, there are no error messages in the console, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Should be ReactDOM.render(<StartPage/>, domContainer);

Comment: @lissettdm ,this does not produce results

Comment: This is not valid <h:link outcome="main">Go to main page</h:link>,

Comment: @lissettdm ,I copied your code, I still have no results, what could be the problem? did I connect something wrong?

Comment: Add  <script type="text/js" src="js/start.js"></script> inside body.  if your script writes page content, it should be placed in the body section

Comment: @lissettdm ,nothing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225269/discussion-between-lissettdm-and-ckaf).

Answer (score 0):

1. The `h:link` is not a valid HTML element and by looks of it it's not defined anywhere.
2. The `StartPage` in render must be component invocation, so instead use this - `<StartPage />`

Here's a working CodeSandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-williamson-xtxwn?file=/src/index.js